# How do I compare values from two tables and add result in third?

Tags: excel

I have the following problem:

Table one has the following columns: ID, Name, Color
Table two has the following columns: ID, Price, Date

I need to make a third table with the following:

1. If ID from table2 is found in ID in table1, then add a row in table3 with: ID, Name, Price

Table1 and Table2 have different size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table3(id, name, price) values(
 select id,name,price from table1, table2 where table1.id=table2.id)
```

I guess ure looking for that

Comment: That is exactly what I need, but in Excel.

Comment: maybe if u are working with tables u shouldn't be using excel? I sugess u export those tables to access and do that there then u can export back to excel.